# Can I use scanf inside an if statement?

Tags: c

```
// take input from user until user enters odd number
# include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    
    do{
        printf("Enter a number :");
        if(scanf("%d",&n)%2 !=0){
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    printf("End");
    return 0;
   
}
```

The code can work if I use `scanf` outside of the `if` but I wanted to know if I can use `scanf` inside the `if` to make the program work.

Comment: Please check what `scanf` *really* [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: You absolutely can, but `scanf` returns the number of items scanned. Your usage doesn't quite make sense, as it `break`s only when a odd number of numbers are successfully scanned. It would suffice to check `if(scanf("%d",&n) > 0 )`if you want to ensure the user entered a number. Otherwise, yes there is nothing wrong with using `scanf` in a loop like this. It will effectively loop until the desired input is provided.

Comment: Ideally, check for the specific number of items you expect to be converted. For example `if(scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3)` if there are three.

Comment: *Can I use scanf inside if loop*. Well, `if` is not a loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the value of `scanf()` is the number of items scanned, not the value that was read. Assuming the scan is successful, it will  always return `1`, not the number the user entered; since this is odd, the loop will end immediately.

You can combine multiple conditions in the `if` using logical operators, so you could write:

```
if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1 || n % 2 != 0) {
    break;
}
```

This will end the loop if either the scan fails (e.g. the user enters something other than a number) or the input is odd.

Comment: It seems more likely, given that nothing is being done with the variable `n` in the loop, the loop is meant to terminate as soon as a number is successfully entered, so when `scanf` returns `1`. The rest of the program can then confidently work with `n` without worrying that it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: The comment says "take input from user until user enters odd number". That's clearly what they were trying to check.

Comment: Anyway I can make it work or I will have use scanf outside loop

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use it outside the `do` loop. Then you won't repeat. `if` is not a loop.